# What to do after fixing the script with git rebase --edit-todo?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I ran `git rebase -i mytag` and, based on [git's reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), used the keyword `drop` instead of removing a line. It seems like my version (2.5.4) doesn't support it, so I got this error:

```
Unknown command: drop aaabbbbccccddddd Update README.md 
Please fix this using 'git rebase --edit-todo'.
```

After running the recommended command, I removed the lines where I added a `drop`, saved and quit the editor. I was hoping `git` would continue the previous rebase process or let me know what to do next. Instead, no message is shown on my CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To continue the previous rebase process, just run `git rebase --continue`.